# How to get values in a Pandas DataFrame using .loc with a MultiIindex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

First time poster here. I'm having some trouble understanding how `.loc` works for a `DataFrame` that has a `MultiIndex`. More specifically, I'm interested in a case where I have a 2 level `MultiIndex` and I want to select values by label of the second level.

For example, using the `DataFrame` defined in the documentation of `loc`:

```py
tuples = [
   ('cobra', 'mark i'), ('cobra', 'mark ii'),
   ('sidewinder', 'mark i'), ('sidewinder', 'mark ii'),
   ('viper', 'mark ii'), ('viper', 'mark iii')
]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
values = [[12, 2], [0, 4], [10, 20],
        [1, 4], [7, 1], [16, 36]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['max_speed', 'shield'], index=index)
df

--------------------------------------
                     max_speed  shield
cobra      mark i           12       2
           mark ii           0       4
sidewinder mark i           10      20
           mark ii           1       4
viper      mark ii           7       1
           mark iii         16      36
```

I want to select the values corresponding to `mark ii`, regardless of the first level label. I can use `xs`:

```py
df.xs("mark ii", level=1)

-----------------------------
            max_speed  shield
cobra               0       4
sidewinder          1       4
viper               7       1
```

And I thought I could use `loc`:

```py
df.loc[:, "mark ii"]

-------------------
KeyError: 'mark ii'
```

However, I get the expected result if I do the following:

```py
df.loc[:, "mark ii", :]    # <-- note the added colon after 'mark ii'

-----------------------------
            max_speed  shield
cobra               0       4
sidewinder          1       4
viper               7       1
```

Can someone explain why `df.loc[:, "mark ii"]` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use directly `:` to specify level. `df.loc[:, "mark ii"]` mean: select all rows (`:`), and the column "mark ii" (which doesn't exist).

The correct approach should be to use [`IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, "mark ii"], :]

# or slice
df.loc[(slice(None), 'mark ii'), :]
```

You can also specify the axis in [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc(axis=0)[:, "mark ii"]
```

Output:

```
                    max_speed  shield
cobra      mark ii          0       4
sidewinder mark ii          1       4
viper      mark ii          7       1
```